# JavaFX TreeView ContextMenu for each TreeItem

Tags: java, javafx

[image: TreeView]

I have this `TreeView` structure.
Category is child of hidden root.
Is there a way to add different `ContextMenu` on right mouse click to each `TreeItem` and not whole `TreeView`.
I can `.setContextMenu()` to `TreeView` but not for `TreeItem`.
Without creating a class `TreeItem`.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by *"Without creating a class TreeItem."*

Comment: Also adding relevant code will make it easier to help.

Comment: Use a cell factory on the `TreeView` and set a different context menu on each cell.